# Reduce Flux to form Mono

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am bit new to Spring Reactive programming. I am trying to get a Flux from I/O, whi
ch returns a list of objects and what to combine to return a Mono from my service.

```
Flux<Obj1> -> Mono<Obj2>

Obj1
{
"a" : "123",
"combine" : "456"
"combine2" : "789"
}

Flux<Obj1> has multiple objects

Obj2
{
"a" : "123"
"combine" : {
              "456" : "1"
            },
"combine2" : {
               "789" : "2"
             }
}

Mono<Obj2> is a consolidation of flux with the Combiner keys.
```

To achieve this, my initial approach is to make sure Flux is completed using then and after that manipulate data.

```
Flux.just(obj1a,obj1b,obj1c)
    .then();
```

But the above statement returns a void of Mono, not sure how may thenMany could work in this case.

I feel missing something here, how should i get control of Flux objects after completion.

Comment: What you need is collect() or reduce(). Check the API documentation.

Comment: My bad it is reduce. Updated the question.

Comment: @VihangShah Try posting code example that can be easily run. Pseudo code is not really helpful in this case.

Answer (score 4):

> To achieve this, my initial approach is to make sure Flux is completed using then and after that manipulate data.

This is the wrong way of thinking for reactive programming - you need to modify the data as it's flowing through the flux. The `then()` methods will *ignore* the results from the flux entirely, and just output some other, unrelated `Mono` when complete.

In the case where you want to take a `Flux` of some element, and want to reduce that down into a `Mono` of some other element, you most likely want the `reduce()` method. That will take an initial `Obj2` in your case, and then a `BiFunction` whose purpose is to take an intermediate `Obj2`, an `Obj1` in the `Flux`, and then produce an updated `Obj2`. The `reduce()` operator will then apply this reduction on the entire stream, giving you a `Mono<Obj2>` at the end.

It's not immediately obvious from your code what you want to achieve specifically, but the following is a related example (lombok used for brevity):

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Obj1 {

    private String a;
    private String combine;
    private String combine2;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class Obj2 {

    private String a;
    private Map<String, Integer> combine = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, Integer> combine2 = new HashMap<>();

}

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux<Obj1> flux = Flux.just(
                new Obj1("123", "456", "789"),
                new Obj1("123", "456", "789"),
                new Obj1("123", "455", "789"));

        Mono<Obj2> mono = flux.reduce(new Obj2(), (o2, o1) -> {
            Map<String, Integer> combine = new HashMap<>(o2.getCombine());
            combine.put(o1.getCombine(), combine.getOrDefault(o1.getCombine(), 0) + 1);
            Map<String, Integer> combine2 = new HashMap<>(o2.getCombine2());
            combine2.put(o1.getCombine2(), combine2.getOrDefault(o1.getCombine2(), 0) + 1);
            return new Obj2(o1.getA(), combine, combine2);
        });

        mono.subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

}
```